Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key while trying to export the private key
My app is already on the Google Play Store, and I want to push a new release of it. When I try to upload an AAB file, I get an error saying, "To upload an Android App Bundle, you must be enrolled in Play app signing." I followed all the steps to export and encrypt the private key using the command below.

java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo
--output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/path/to/encryption_public_key.pem

But when I run the above command, I get the following error:

Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider
supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:574)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:284)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)
at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)

Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue?

I prefer not to see a screenshot of an error. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?. Also, what is pepk.jar?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk We downloaded the pepk.jar file from the Google Play Store and provided the path of it on the command.

I fixed this issue by referring to the below video. Thank you.
youtube.com/watch?v=pCczRHsdNOY
